# Remote debugging w/ Eclipse CDT gdbserver: stdin/stdout

Tags: eclipse-cdt, remote-debugging, gdbserver

OK, this seems pretty basic, but no luck. I'm using Eclipse Helios w/ CDT. Both host & target are linux boxes. I've been starting my application on the target machine with:

> gdbserver :port my_app

and successfully attaching from eclipse using a "C/C++ Attach to Application" debug configuration. My application's stdout is displayed on the target system, but stdin doesn't go to my app. In eclipse, I have a console for gdb (commands) and gdb trace, but no application console like when debugging locally. The debug configuration "Allocate Console" check-box just controls whether or not I get a gdb command console.

I tried starting the application separately and attaching (using gdbserver --multi). This was worse: eclipse/gdb didn't see all running threads and stdin on the target tty resulted in

> Child terminated with signal = 0x5 (SIGTRAP)
>
> Trace/breakpoint trap

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. Application std in/out will go to the terminal you used to start the gdbserver (and application) from. Eclipse cannot redirect those.